# Deletion of some watchdog messages with subquery

Tags: 7, database, log-messages

What i want is to delete from watchdog the first 20 messages with type as 'blabla' what i did untill now is:

```
 $query = db_select('watchdog', 'w')
    ->fields('w')
    ->condition('type', 'blabla')
    ->range(0, 250);
  $subquery = $query->execute()->fetchCol('wid');

  if ($subquery != NULL) {

    db_delete('watchdog')
      ->condition('wid', $subquery, 'IN')
      ->execute();
  }
```

it works fine but i want to do it with subquery like:

```
$subquery = db_select('watchdog', 'w')
    ->fields('w', array('wid'))
    ->condition('type', 'blabla')
    ->range(0, 250);

  // Deletes the previous selected values.
  db_delete('watchdog')
    ->condition($subquery, 'wid')
    ->execute();
```

it gives me the error:

```
General error: 1093 You can't specify target table 'watchdog' for update in FROM clause
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You were close; this should work for you:

```
$subquery = db_select('watchdog', 'w')
  ->fields('w', array('wid'))
  ->condition('type', 'blabla')
  ->range(0, 250)
  ->execute()
  ->fetchCol('wid');

// Deletes the previous selected values.
db_delete('watchdog')
  ->condition('wid', $subquery, 'IN')
  ->execute();
```

You weren't executing the subquery (meaning there were no results), and you mixed up the order of arguments passed to query condition.

Comment: if i do not use "if ($subquery != NULL) {" gives me error "Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '))" this is when no blabla type exists on watchdog.

Comment: Got it now; I thought you wanted to execute the query and get results in one "go". You will have to check if you have results in the subquery, because the "IN" condition in MySQL requires arguments to be passed. You could do this using some more complex expression, but honestly this is more readable and maintainable.

Comment: Is there any other solution, like doing some subquery?